# vagrant, port forwarding, and iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, vagrant

Background: I am a newby learning Python and Django. Because my machine is Windows 8.1, I installed Vagrant with Precise 64. At first things were fine, then suddenly, NONE of my projects in the VM would show up locally. To make matters worse (in my mind, at least) all 3 of my browsers gave different messages. Chrome said I had an 'empty response', 
firefox said 'the connection has been reset', and IE says 'the page cannot be dsiplayed'. I figured the problem was in Vagrant because my very first Django project, on Windows, still comes up in the browser, and the three Vagrant projects all have different database settings so it isn't the database.

I went to the Vagrant google group and found two similar prior questions, but both were unresolved. One suggestion there was to run iptables -L, so I did:

```
(fed1-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/fed1$ iptables -L
FATAL: Error inserting ip_tables (/lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/
netfilter/ip_tables.ko): Operation not permitted
iptables v1.4.12: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist
(do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
(fed1-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/fed1$
```

I don't know what any of this means. I've never even heard of insmod. I googled some more but I am just getting lost in the woods. I thought of just reinstalling iptables, but then I read that this is not turned on in Ubuntu by default. That tells me it wasn't there when the local sites were working in my browser. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984217/vagrants-port-forwarding-not-working) on SO but when I tried it I got:

```
vagrant@precise64:/home$ curl -v 'http://localhost:80'
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
vagrant@precise64:/home$ curl -v 'http://localhost:8000'
* About to connect() to localhost port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
vagrant@precise64:/home$ curl -v 'http://localhost:8888'
* About to connect() to localhost port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

The reason I tried 8000 and 8888 is that my vagrant box has forwarded 8000 to 8888 on the host.

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host) but couldn't get past the syntax error even though the first version is exactly as it was written in the answer:

```
vagrant@precise64:/home$ $ch = curl_init("http://google.com");
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
vagrant@precise64:/home$ $ch = curl_init("http://google.com"); curl_setopt($ch,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); $data = curl_exec($ch); print($data);
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
vagrant@precise64:/home$ $ch = curl_init ("http://google.com"); curl_setopt($ch
, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); $data = curl_exec($ch); print($data);
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
vagrant@precise64:/home$
```

So I don't know what to do and anything I do from here forward is just guessing. Suggestions, please? Thanx.

Comment: Tried rebooting the VM? I usually get that error when my kernel gets updated in Arch Linux (but it has never happened to me in Ubuntu). Rebooting to fully shift to the new kernel always fixed it for me. `iptables` is usually turned on by default, dunno where you read that. That last code is PHP, not bash, so running it in the shell isn't of much use.

Comment: @muru 1. I read that in the same SO article I linked to. It is in the 3rd paragraph of the selected answer: "The default Vagrant VM (Ubuntu) doesn't come with a firewall set up". He also says if the curl to localhost doesn't work, it isn't port forwarding. So I don't know where to go next.

Comment: I think he means that iptables isn't configured to block anything. iptables is usually enabled, but the default rules are all simply ACCEPT. Oddly you can't even connect to localhost. Is the service running? What happens when you try to start the Django server? Also, did the iptables error persist after restarting the VM?

Comment: Django - I have never had an error when I execute runserver itself.

Comment: I don't know how to make this forum work I hit return and it wants to save and quit. \n. Anyway,  ufw is status inactive. When I tried to enable it. I got a warning that it might disrupt ssh. Since I didn't know what that would do or if it would break my connection to my box, I left it alone. \n. After reboot, I got :   G:\gswd-vagrant>vagrant up
Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.

Comment: Press shift-enter (kinda like facebook comments) - but it won't make any difference, comments always get stripped of new lines.
Before we get around this, we need to fix the Vagrant/VirtualBox thing, and unfortunately this is not the best place for that. Try [su], and when you got that fixed, we'll get back to this one.

Comment: I found out that when VirtualBox pushed their software update, they made the path to VBoxManager different from the env var Vagrant installs automatically, hence the disconnect. Supposedly Vagrant will fix this, but all I had to do was change my env var to match what VirtualBox wanted, reboot and voila! I'm back in business.

Comment: So Django is working fine now as well?

Comment: Well, no. It keeps giving me the error that it can't find the model I imported from windows (sqlite3 to postgres in the VM). My best guess is that it is looking in projectname/appname/ when I have a modular setup so it should be looking in projectname/appname/apps, and I don't know how to tell it to look elsewhere. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Best I can Google is http://codespatter.com/2009/04/10/how-to-add-locations-to-python-path-for-reusable-django-apps/.

Comment: Thanks, muru, for your time, thoughts, and energy. Quite apart from this path nonsense, I still can't get my other vagrant projects to come up locally in my browser, so until that's resolved, if ever, there's not much point in even using vagrant. As for the link, I think he is saying to put an app directly on pythonpath if you plan on moving it and making it reusable, which isn't my situation yet. Otherwise, if the project is on the path, then the apps under it have to be also, right? Anyway, thanks and all the best to you.